# Actualizar fecha con un trigger o event en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

**

> Hola estimados, tengo una duda respecto como puedo actualizar las
>   fechas de una tabla automáticamente desde mysql, con un trigger o un
>   event.

**

pongo ejemplo una logica...

```
 if(fechainicio < fechaactual)
   {        
      actualizar a la fecha actual
   }

 else
  {
  no actualizar
  }
```

por favor si pueden ayudarme.

Comment: Estimado se puede hacer perfectamente mediante un `TRIGGER`, pero debe Ud. indicar cuál será el evento que lanzará el `TRIGGER`: una inserción, actualización, eliminación de una fila de la tabla, etc. Qué ha investigado sobre los trigger, qué dificultades tiene. O, si es en PHP donde necesita hacerlo. Son dos cosas diferentes y falta contexto en la pregunta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

puedes crear el event indicándole en que tiempo se ejecutara ejemplo

```
CREATE EVENT `cambiar_fecha` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY 
DO update tabla
set fecha_cambia= now()
where
fechainicio<now()
```

también debes verificar que el servidor de mysql este habilitado:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```